# Problems to sync databases with drush

Tags: drush

I have some problems with drush sql sync function

When the password prompt comes up I've used the Linux root user pass of the remote servers root user

Has anyone an Idea what I could do to fix this?

Here is the content of my alias file

```
$aliases['live'] = array(
  'uri' => 'www.eso-meetu.de',
  'root' => '/var/www/virtual/eso-meetu.de/htdocs',
  'remote-user' => 'root',
  'remote-host' => 'eso-meetu.de',
  'ssh-options' => '-o PasswordAuthentication=yes',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%dump-dir' => '/tmp',
    '%pubimg' => '/var/www/virtual/eso-meetu/htdocs/sites/default/files',
  ),
  'command-specific' => array(
    'sql-sync' => array(
      'no-cache' => TRUE,
    ),
  ),
  'databases' => array(
    'default' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'database' => 'meetu_original',
        'username' => 'usernameremoverd',
        'password' => 'passwordremoved',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'prefix' => '',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
      ),
    ),
  ),   
);

$aliases['self'] = array(
  'uri' => 'www.drupal.dev',
  'root' => 'var/www/',
  'path-aliases' => array(
    '%pubimg' => '/var/www/sites/default/files',
  ),
  'databases' => array(
    'default' => array(
      'default' => array(
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'database' => 'drupal',
        'username' => 'drupal',
        'password' => 'drupal',
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'prefix' => '',
        'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci', 
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Here comes the output from drush verbose:

```
user@drupal:~/html$ drush sql-sync @self @live -d -v
 Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.01 sec, 4.35 MB]                                   [bootstrap]
 Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [0.01 sec, 4.36 MB] [bootstrap]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [0.01 sec, 4.45 MB]
 Cache HIT cid:                                                                         [debug]
 7.0-dev-commandfiles-0-d59e04c348899678368fc648b2c8da2b [0.01 sec,
 4.46 MB]
 Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.06 sec, 11.35 MB]                                 [bootstrap]
 Bootstrap to phase 0. [0.09 sec, 11.35 MB]                                 [bootstrap]
 Found command: sql-sync (commandfile=sql) [0.09 sec, 11.35 MB]        [bootstrap]
 Including                                                                           [bootstrap]
 /home/user/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/sql/sync.sql.inc
[0.15 sec, 11.39 MB]
Calling hook drush_sql_sync_validate [0.15 sec, 11.46 MB]                    [debug]
Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
[0.15 sec, 11.48 MB]
Loaded alias @live from file                                                       [notice]
/var/www/sites/all/drush/aliases.drushrc.php [0.28 sec, 11.49 MB]
Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php  -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d                  [command]
magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off
/home/user/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php
--php-options=' -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off
-d magic_quotes_sybase=Off'  --backend=2 --verbose --debug
--root=/var/www --uri=http://default  sql-conf   --all 2>&1 [0.37
sec, 11.51 MB]
/usr/bin/php  -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d     [notice]
magic_quotes_sybase=Off
/home/user/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php 
--php-options=' -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off
-d magic_quotes_sybase=Off'  --backend=2 --verbose --debug
--root=/var/www --uri=http://default  sql-conf   --all 2>&1 [0.37
sec, 11.51 MB]
You will destroy data in eso-meetu.de/meetu_original and replace with data from drupal.
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
Returned from hook drush_sql_sync_validate [4.84 sec, 11.53 MB]            [debug]
Calling hook drush_sql_sync [4.84 sec, 11.55 MB]                               [debug]
Starting to dump database on Source. [4.91 sec, 11.56 MB]               [ok]
Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
[4.91 sec, 11.57 MB]
Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php  -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d                  [command]
magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off
/home/user/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php
--php-options=' -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off
-d magic_quotes_sybase=Off'  --backend=2 --verbose --debug --strict=0
--root=/var/www --uri=http://default  sql-dump   --gzip --result-file
2>&1 [5.02 sec, 11.7 MB]
/usr/bin/php  -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d     [notice]
magic_quotes_sybase=Off
/home/user/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php
 --php-options=' -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off
 -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off'  --backend=2 --verbose --debug --strict=0
 --root=/var/www --uri=http://default  sql-dump   --gzip --result-file
  2>&1 [5.02 sec, 11.71 MB]
  Bootstrap to phase 0. [5.05 sec, 4.35 MB]                           [bootstrap]
  Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [5.05 sec, 4.36 MB] [bootstrap]
  Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [5.05 sec, 4.45 MB]
 Cache HIT cid:                                                             [debug]
 7.0-dev-commandfiles-0-d59e04c348899678368fc648b2c8da2b [5.05 sec,
 4.47 MB]
 Bootstrap to phase 0. [5.1 sec, 11.35 MB]                                   [bootstrap]
 Bootstrap to phase 0. [5.13 sec, 11.36 MB]                                 [bootstrap]
 Found command: sql-dump (commandfile=sql) [5.13 sec, 11.36 MB]        [bootstrap]
 Calling hook drush_sql_dump [5.19 sec, 11.42 MB]                               [debug]
 Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [5.19 sec,     [bootstrap]
 11.42 MB]
 Initialized Drupal 7.30 root directory at /var/www [5.2 sec, 13.09       [notice]
 MB]
 Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [5.2 sec,      [bootstrap]
 13.09 MB]
 Initialized Drupal site default at sites/default [5.2 sec, 13.1 MB]      [notice]
 Cache HIT cid:                                                                         [debug]
 7.0-dev-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [5.2 sec,
 13.1 MB]
 Cache HIT cid:                                                                         [debug]
 7.0-dev-commandfiles-2-f1f919de142adb82dd89194b63606c3b [5.2 sec,
 13.11 MB]
 Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration() [5.21[bootstrap]
 sec, 14.53 MB]
 sql-query: SHOW TABLES; [5.22 sec, 14.73 MB]                               [status]
 Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_KDqlDn --database=drupal --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drush_TpJfBn
  actions
  authmap
  batch
  block
  block_custom
  block_node_type
  block_role
  blocked_ips
  breakpoint_group
  breakpoints
  cache
 cache_block
 cache_bootstrap
 cache_entity_comment
 cache_entity_file
 cache_entity_message
 cache_entity_message_type
 cache_entity_message_type_category
 cache_entity_node
 cache_entity_og_membership
 cache_entity_og_membership_type
 cache_entity_registration
 cache_entity_registration_state
 cache_entity_registration_type
 cache_entity_taxonomy_term
 cache_entity_taxonomy_vocabulary
 cache_entity_user
 cache_field
 cache_filter
 cache_form
 cache_image
 cache_libraries
 cache_media_oembed
 cache_menu
 cache_metatag
 cache_page
 cache_panels
 cache_path
 cache_rules
 cache_token
 cache_update
 cache_views
 cache_views_data
 ckeditor_input_format
 ckeditor_settings
 comment
 ctools_css_cache
 ctools_object_cache
 date_format_locale
 date_format_type
 date_formats
 facetapi
 field_config
 field_config_instance
 field_data_body
 field_data_comment_body
 field_data_field_address
 field_data_field_approving_user
 field_data_field_bio
 field_data_field_confirmation
 field_data_field_date
 field_data_field_facebook_url
 field_data_field_file_image_alt_text
 field_data_field_file_image_title_text
 field_data_field_group_logo
 field_data_field_linkedin_url
 field_data_field_location
 field_data_field_logo
 field_data_field_media
 field_data_field_membership_token
 field_data_field_message_rendered_body
 field_data_field_message_rendered_subject
 field_data_field_my_request
 field_data_field_name_first
 field_data_field_name_last
 field_data_field_number_of_attendees
 field_data_field_offsite_url
 field_data_field_og_access_default_value
 field_data_field_og_subscribe_settings
 field_data_field_organizers
 field_data_field_original_og_membership
 field_data_field_radioactivity
 field_data_field_registration
 field_data_field_registration_type
 field_data_field_related_question
 field_data_field_requesting_user
 field_data_field_response_date
 field_data_field_target_comments
 field_data_field_target_nodes
 field_data_field_target_users
 field_data_field_topics
 field_data_field_twitter_url
 field_data_group_access
 field_data_group_content_access
 field_data_group_group
 field_data_message_subscribe_email
 field_data_message_text
 field_data_og_group_ref
 field_data_og_membership_request
 field_data_og_roles_permissions
 field_data_og_user_group_ref
 field_data_og_user_node
 field_data_og_user_user
 field_data_title_field
 field_data_user_trusted_contacts
 field_revision_body
 field_revision_comment_body
 field_revision_field_address
 field_revision_field_approving_user
 field_revision_field_bio
 field_revision_field_confirmation
 field_revision_field_date
 field_revision_field_facebook_url
 field_revision_field_file_image_alt_text
 field_revision_field_file_image_title_text
 field_revision_field_group_logo
 field_revision_field_linkedin_url
 field_revision_field_location
 field_revision_field_logo
 field_revision_field_media
 field_revision_field_membership_token
 field_revision_field_message_rendered_body
 field_revision_field_message_rendered_subject
 field_revision_field_my_request
 field_revision_field_name_first
 field_revision_field_name_last
 field_revision_field_number_of_attendees
 field_revision_field_offsite_url
 field_revision_field_og_access_default_value
 field_revision_field_og_subscribe_settings
 field_revision_field_organizers
 field_revision_field_original_og_membership
 field_revision_field_radioactivity
 field_revision_field_registration
 field_revision_field_registration_type
 field_revision_field_related_question
 field_revision_field_requesting_user
 field_revision_field_response_date
 field_revision_field_target_comments
 field_revision_field_target_nodes
 field_revision_field_target_users
 field_revision_field_topics
 field_revision_field_twitter_url
 field_revision_group_access
 field_revision_group_content_access
 field_revision_group_group
 field_revision_message_subscribe_email
 field_revision_message_text
 field_revision_og_group_ref
 field_revision_og_membership_request
 field_revision_og_roles_permissions
 field_revision_og_user_group_ref
 field_revision_og_user_node
 field_revision_og_user_user
 field_revision_title_field
 field_revision_user_trusted_contacts
 file_display
 file_managed
 file_metadata
 file_type
 file_usage
 filter
 filter_format
 flag_content
 flag_counts
 flag_types
 flags
 flood
 history
 image_effects
 image_styles
 media_oembed_provider
 menu_custom
 menu_links
 menu_router
 message
 message_type
 message_type_category
 metatag
 metatag_config
 node
 node_access
 node_comment_statistics
 node_revision
 node_type
 og_membership
 og_membership_type
 og_role
 og_role_permission
 og_users_roles
 page_manager_handlers
 page_manager_pages
 page_manager_weights
  panelizer_defaults
  panelizer_entity
  panels_display
  panels_layout
  panels_pane
  panels_renderer_pipeline
  pm_disable
  pm_index
  pm_message
  poll
  poll_choice
  poll_vote
  queue
  quicktabs
  radioactivity_decay_profile
  radioactivity_deferred_incidents
  radioactivity_flood_map
  radioactivity_history
  rate_bot_agent
  rate_bot_ip
  rdf_mapping
  realname
  redirect
  registration
  registration_entity
  registration_state
  registration_type
  registry
  registry_file
  role
  role_permission
  rules_config
  rules_dependencies
 rules_tags
 rules_trigger
 search_dataset
 search_index
 search_node_links
 search_total
 semaphore
 sequences
 sessions
 shortcut_set
 shortcut_set_users
 system
 taxonomy_index
 taxonomy_term_data
 taxonomy_term_hierarchy
 taxonomy_vocabulary
 url_alias
 users
 users_roles
 variable
 views_display
 views_view
 votingapi_cache
 votingapi_vote
 watchdog
 Calling system(mysqldump --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_QUVbLn  drupal --host=localhost --result-file     
 /home/user/drush-backups/drupal/20140802092251/drupal_20140802_092252.sql --no-autocommit --single-transaction --opt -Q  && gzip -f       
 /home/user/drush-backups/drupal/20140802092251/drupal_20140802_092252.sql);
 Database dump saved to                                                          [success]
 /home/user/drush-backups/drupal/20140802092251/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz
 [5.85 sec, 14.83 MB]
  Returned from hook drush_sql_dump [5.85 sec, 14.83 MB]                       [debug]
  Command dispatch complete [5.85 sec, 14.79 MB]                                [notice]
  Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec)
  page   0.637       1       637.04
 Peak memory usage was 15.17 MB [5.85 sec, 14.99 MB]                          [memory]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [5.85 sec, 15.01 MB]
 Starting to discover temporary files directory on Destination. [5.87 [ok]
 sec, 11.77 MB]
 Backend invoke: ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes root@eso-meetu.de     [command]
 'drush  --backend=2 --verbose --debug --uri=www.eso-meetu.de
 --root=/var/www/virtual/eso-meetu.de/htdocs  php-eval '\''return
 drush_find_tmp();'\'' 2>&1' 2>&1 [6.04 sec, 11.78 MB]
 ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes root@eso-meetu.de 'drush                 [notice]
 --backend=2 --verbose --debug --uri=www.eso-meetu.de
 --root=/var/www/virtual/eso-meetu.de/htdocs  php-eval '\''return
 drush_find_tmp();'\'' 2>&1' 2>&1 [6.04 sec, 11.79 MB]
 root@eso-meetu.de's password: 
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [15.38 sec, 11.84 MB]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [15.39 sec, 11.84 MB]
 Backend invoke: /usr/bin/php  -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d                  [command]
 magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off
 /home/user/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php
 --php-options=' -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off
 -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off'  --backend=2 --yes --verbose --debug
 --root=/var/www --uri=http://default  core-rsync
 '@self:/home/user/drush-backups/drupal/20140802092251/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz'
 '@self:/tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz'   --remove-source-files
 2>&1 [15.54 sec, 11.85 MB]
 /usr/bin/php  -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off -d     [notice]
 magic_quotes_sybase=Off
 /home/user/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php --php=/usr/bin/php
 --php-options=' -d magic_quotes_gpc=Off -d magic_quotes_runtime=Off
 -d magic_quotes_sybase=Off'  --backend=2 --yes --verbose --debug
 --root=/var/www --uri=http://default  core-rsync
 '@self:/home/user/drush-backups/drupal/20140802092251/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz'
 '@self:/tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz'   --remove-source-files
 2>&1 [15.54 sec, 11.86 MB]
 Bootstrap to phase 0. [15.57 sec, 4.35 MB]                                 [bootstrap]
 Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drush() [15.57 sec, 4.36 MB][bootstrap]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [15.57 sec, 4.45 MB]
 Cache HIT cid:                                                                         [debug]
 7.0-dev-commandfiles-0-d59e04c348899678368fc648b2c8da2b [15.58 sec,
 4.47 MB]
 Bootstrap to phase 0. [15.69 sec, 11.36 MB]                                [bootstrap]
 Bootstrap to phase 0. [15.72 sec, 11.36 MB]                                [bootstrap]
 Found command: core-rsync (commandfile=core) [15.72 sec, 11.36 MB]   [bootstrap]
 Including                                                                           [bootstrap]
 /home/user/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/rsync.core.inc
 [15.81 sec, 11.38 MB]
 Calling hook drush_core_rsync [15.82 sec, 11.48 MB]                           [debug]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [15.82 sec, 11.5 MB]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [15.82 sec, 11.5 MB]
  Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
  [15.82 sec, 11.5 MB]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [15.91 sec, 11.51 MB]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [15.92 sec, 11.51 MB]
 You will destroy data from /tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz and replace with data from /home/user/drush-backups/drupal/20140802092251/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz
 Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
  Calling system(rsync -e 'ssh ' -akzv --exclude=".git" --exclude=".gitignore" --exclude=".hg" --exclude=".hgignore" --exclude=".hgrags" --exclude=".bzr"       
  --exclude=".bzrignore" --exclude=".bzrtags" --exclude=".svn" --stats --progress --remove-source-files       
 /home/user/drush-backups/drupal/20140802092251/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz /tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz);
 sending incremental file list
 drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz
   925847 100%  106.46MB/s     0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)

 Number of files: 1
 Number of files transferred: 1
 Total file size: 925847 bytes
 Total transferred file size: 925847 bytes
 Literal data: 925847 bytes
 Matched data: 0 bytes
 File list size: 58
 File list generation time: 0.001 seconds
 File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
 Total bytes sent: 926266
 Total bytes received: 31

 sent 926266 bytes  received 31 bytes  617531.33 bytes/sec
 total size is 925847  speedup is 1.00
 Returned from hook drush_core_rsync [16.08 sec, 11.66 MB]                    [debug]
 Command dispatch complete [16.08 sec, 11.61 MB]                               [notice]
 Peak memory usage was 14.92 MB [16.08 sec, 11.6 MB]                          [memory]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--8bf32223596c4e7624f626b4fa56d306      [debug]
 [16.08 sec, 11.6 MB]
 Copying dump file from Source to Destination. [16.12 sec, 11.86 MB]  [ok]
 Starting to import dump file onto Destination database. [16.12 sec,  [ok]
 11.86 MB]
 Backend invoke: ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes root@eso-meetu.de     [command]
 'drush  --backend=2 --verbose --debug --strict=0
 --uri=www.eso-meetu.de --root=/var/www/virtual/eso-meetu.de/htdocs
 sql-query   --file=/tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz --file-delete
 2>&1' 2>&1 [16.3 sec, 11.88 MB]
 ssh -o PasswordAuthentication=yes root@eso-meetu.de 'drush                 [notice]
 --backend=2 --verbose --debug --strict=0 --uri=www.eso-meetu.de
 --root=/var/www/virtual/eso-meetu.de/htdocs  sql-query
 --file=/tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz --file-delete 2>&1' 2>&1
 [16.3 sec, 11.89 MB]
 root@eso-meetu.de's password:
 Starting Drush preflight. [17.63 sec, 1.99 MB]                            [preflight]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--55ad758669c686ea540e62d1ca109d5b      [debug]
 [17.63 sec, 2.04 MB]
 Cache HIT cid:                                                                         [debug]
 7.0-dev-commandfiles-0-087331b5bed7344fe80ba1b1fea51261 [17.64 sec,
 2.06 MB]
 Bootstrap to phase 0. [17.7 sec, 5.65 MB]                                   [bootstrap]
 Bootstrap to phase 0. [17.74 sec, 5.66 MB]                                 [bootstrap]
 Found command: sql-query (commandfile=sql) [17.74 sec, 5.66 MB]       [bootstrap]
 Calling hook drush_sql_query [17.81 sec, 5.7 MB]                               [debug]
 Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_root() [17.81 sec,   [bootstrap]
 5.7 MB]
 Initialized Drupal 7.30 root directory at                                      [notice]
 /var/www/virtual/eso-meetu.de/htdocs [17.83 sec, 6.64 MB]
 Cache HIT cid:                                                                         [debug]
 7.0-dev-commandfiles-1-1b1f76beae8b3fa873220937ec1d95e2 [17.83 sec,
 6.64 MB]
 Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_site() [17.83 sec,   [bootstrap]
 6.64 MB]
 Initialized Drupal site www.eso-meetu.de at sites/default [17.83 sec,   [notice]
 6.65 MB]
 Cache HIT cid:                                                                         [debug]
 7.0-dev-install_profile-66ecfeb9791a023150773849f1550c5d [17.83 sec,
 6.65 MB]
 Cache HIT cid:                                                                         [debug]
 7.0-dev-commandfiles-2-f1f919de142adb82dd89194b63606c3b [17.83 sec,
 6.66 MB]
 Drush bootstrap phase : _drush_bootstrap_drupal_configuration()       [bootstrap]
 [17.84 sec, 7.4 MB]


finfo::file(/tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz): failed to open           [warning]
 stream: No such file or directory drush.inc:842 [17.84 sec, 7.52 MB]
 Examining /tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz headers. [17.84 sec,         [debug]
 7.52 MB]
 fopen(/tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz): failed to open stream: No      [warning]
 such file or directory drush.inc:854 [17.84 sec, 7.52 MB]
 Unable to open /tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz. [17.84 sec, 7.52       [warning]
 MB]
 Examining /tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz extension. [17.84 sec,       [debug]
 7.52 MB]
 Unable to determine mime type for drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz.          [error]
 [19.05 sec, 11.96 MB]
 Executing: mysql --defaults-extra-file=/tmp/drush_Ba0Nob --database=meetu_original --host=localhost --silent  < /tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz
 sh: 1: Query failed. [19.08 sec, 11.97 MB]                                   [error]
 Returned from hook drush_sql_query [17.85 sec, 7.52 MB]                      [debug]
 Command dispatch complete [17.85 sec, 7.5 MB]                                [notice]
 Peak memory usage was 7.78 MB [17.85 sec, 7.61 MB]                           [memory]
 Cache MISS cid: 7.0-dev-alias-path--55ad758669c686ea540e62d1ca109d5b         [debug]
 [17.85 sec, 7.62 MB]
 cannot open /tmp/drupal_20140802_092252.sql.gz: No such file
  Timer  Cum (sec)  Count  Avg (msec)
  page   0.006       1       5.99
 Returned from hook drush_sql_sync [19.09 sec, 11.89 MB]                      [debug]
 Command dispatch complete [19.09 sec, 11.84 MB]                               [notice]
 Peak memory usage was 15.4 MB [19.09 sec, 11.83 MB]                          [memory]
 user@drupal:~/html$
```

Comment: It looks like your SQL dump didn't go up to the server. Please show us the contents of your drush aliases file for @live. You should also set up SSH keys and config to your live server.

Comment: Whats the file name of your drush aliases file? Is it the master file? Generally I'd've thought @self was protected. My pattern is more like drush sql-sync \@self \@meetu.live

Comment: Your aliases file doesn't need so much stuff in it. Drush will use the default settings file from source and destination to determine most things automatically. You also have a typoh in self root. Dont use self either. Use dev or local as self is protected. Or just remove it from aliases.

Answer (score 1):

From your error log its almost clear that the SQL dump file which was created in local server didn't moved to the remote production server. 
So this error `finfo::file(/tmp/drupal_20140801_224144.sql.gz): failed to open` happened. 
Have a good look at your alias file and see if you want to add some SSH validations in the server. Generally remote servers do need this setup. For further information look at this link ['drush rsync' not excluding paths specified in 'exclude-paths' in "aliases.drushrc.php"](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24841/drush-rsync-not-excluding-paths-specified-in-exclude-paths-in-aliases-drush). 
Also try to debug with verbose mode with `drush -v -d sql-sync @oldsite @newsite`.

Let me know if you have any further issues in this.

Comment: additional information are now given in the original question